# Warning: Illegal string offset 'order' in functions-core.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I work with an Wordpress theme which is not being updated. However, the server has a new version of PHP.

The problem is that I can not login to Wordpress; I see these errors:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'order' in /home/minne/domains/civ-lauwersoog.nl/public_html/wp-content/themes/civ/core/functions-core.php on line 19

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/minne/domains/civ-lauwersoog.nl/public_html/wp-content/themes/civ/core/functions-core.php:19) in /home/minne/domains/civ-lauwersoog.nl/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 866
```

This fourth line in the following section is line 19 which generates the error:

```
function yiw_subval_sort( $a, $subkey ) {
if( is_array( $a ) AND ! empty( $a ) ) {
    foreach( $a as $k => $v ) {
        $b[$k] = strtolower( $v[$subkey] );
    }

    asort( $b );

    foreach( $b as $key => $val ) {
        $c[] = $a[$key];
    }

    return $c;
}

return $a;
}
```

I really hope someone could help me out with this issue.

Best Regards,

Peter

Comment: yiw_subval_sort itself is just returning data, your problem is likely whatever function is calling it and echoing it after headers are sent.

Comment: Your code are trying to access the 'order'-key in $v on line 4 but because it doesn't exists it outputs an error. And you are not allowed to output anything before you call header() or setcookie() or similar functions

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I am not a web developer. I am sorry. I do not know ho to solve it. I will add it to my question that I don't know PHP. Could someone please clarify how I could solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the keys does exist ..

**$b** and **$subkey** not defined inside the function you provided.

```
function yiw_subval_sort( $a, $subkey ) {
    if( is_array( $a ) AND ! empty( $a ) ) {
        foreach( $a as $k => $v ) {
            if( isset( $b[$k] ) && isset( $v[$subkey] ) )
                $b[$k] = strtolower( $v[$subkey] );
    }
```

Comment: also check `$subkey` not empty and has proper data type.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I replaced my firts line of code with these lines; but I only get more errors now. I am sorry; I am not a web developer, so this is difficult for me to solve.

Comment: Thank you for replying Hutchbat. This is the link to the file : http://pastebin.com/7sx8gCU7