# Warning: Illegal string offset 'order' in ---upgrading php version

Tags: php, string, wordpress

So I'm getting this error:

> **Warning**: Illegal string offset 'order' in
>   /home/ocnjsurf/public_html/wp-content/themes/sheeva/core/functions-core.php
>   on line 19

This occurred after I upgraded to php 5.445

The code they are referencing is:

```
function yiw_subval_sort( $a, $subkey ) {
    if( is_array( $a ) AND ! empty( $a ) ) {
        foreach( $a as $k => $v ) {
             $b[$k] = strtolower( $v[$subkey] ); <== this is line 19
        }

        asort( $b );

        foreach( $b as $key => $val ) {
            $c[] = $a[$key];
        }

        return $c;
    }

    return $a;
}
```

So I'm not sure how to fix the error it's on this site: http://oceancitynjsurfschool.com/ and It's a Wordpress site, I can't login to the backend.

Comment: Answerless dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23753157/warning-illegal-string-offset-order-in-functions-core-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correct this Illegal String Offset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361392/how-do-i-correct-this-illegal-string-offset)